# Editable only by logged in user

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I would like to be able to call an ajax php function to tell me if the user is permitted to edit the calendar.

I suspect that I need to call the ajax function and then set editable to true or false?
Does fullcalendar have some kind on initialisation method that is called before rendering?

Can anyone advise? Thanks.

Comment: No, but you could call the AJAX function and only initialise fullCalendar after the AJAX has returned. While that will help your UI, it wouldn't stop someone from changing the value back again if they so wished and had the knowledge. So to provide real security you would also need to check again when the user tries to save an event back to your server, whether they have permission to do so or not.

Comment: Thank you. I had just figured out the first part myself (I should have got that earlier!).
Great advice for the security issue. I will certainly do that.